# Curl connection refused on circleci but works on local machine

Tags: http, curl, wget, circleci, connection-refused

I have a circleci pipeline, and after deployment I run a smoke test to check the application status. This is the code below:

```
smoke-test:
    docker:
      - image: python:3.10.5-alpine3.16
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: Install dependencies
          command: |
            apk add --update --no-cache curl aws-cli tar gzip jq
      - run:
          name: Backend smoke test
          command: |
            export BACKEND_IP=$(aws ec2 describe-instances \
              --filters "Name=tag:Name,Values=UdaPeople-backend-${CIRCLE_WORKFLOW_ID:0:5}" \
                'Name=instance-state-name,Values=running' \
              --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].PublicIpAddress' \
              --output text)

            export API_URL="http://${BACKEND_IP}:3030/api/status"
            echo "${API_URL}"
            wget  "${API_URL}"
            if curl -s -v "${API_URL}" | grep "ok"
            then 
              return 0
            else 
              return 1
            fi
```

More details:

- the server I am trying to query is an ec2 instance with a security group that allows all IP addresses on port 3030
- I downloaded the container I am using in circle ci and tested the curl command and wget. It works perfectly
- I have made more than 30 deployments, and the result is the same
- The error output from circleci shows that it actually hits the IP address.
- I increased the timeout seconds and also set the retries to 5

Please what could I be missing?

[image]

Comment: Are you able to open `http://52.91.76.254:3030/api/status` in your browser?

Comment: Do you have an inbound rule to accept traffic from any source going to port 80?